# Unable to Configure IIS in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, iis-6

I am trying to install IIS in Windows Server 2008 R2 ,But facing with below error .An can one help me in knowing what's the issue is for and how can I solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lights:
1st. Make sure your server is up to date.
https://forums.iis.net/p/1148533/1893624.aspx
https://forums.iis.net/p/1148533/2034662.aspx

if you had it already installed it somewhere take it out and reinstall the feature.

make sure that all .net updates are in place and up to date.